# using same method for multiple buttons for mouse pressed and touch pressed events

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

I am using scenebuilder to make the UI. I want to make the color of the buttons change when mouse is pressed or when the button is touched. Can I set the same method for both mouse pressed and screen touched events and also set the same events for multiple buttons? Like there are 3 buttons and I want to change their color in mouse pressed and screen touched events and use only one method for all.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say, you have three buttons

```
Button button1 = new Button();
Button button2 = new Button();
Button button3 = new Button();
```

Create a method saying

```
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
     // Button was clicked, change color
     ((Button)event.getTarget).setStyle("-fx-background-color:PINK");
}
```

All buttons have a `setOnAction()` which is fired on both `mouse pressed` and `screen touched events`.

**JavaDoc says**

> The button's action, which is invoked whenever the button is fired.
>   This may be due to the user clicking on the button with the mouse, or
>   by a touch event, or by a key press, or if the developer
>   programmatically invokes the fire() method.

Use it :

```
button1.setOnAction(this::handleButtonAction);
button2.setOnAction(this::handleButtonAction);
button3.setOnAction(this::handleButtonAction);
```

**If you are using FXML**

You can define one action for all buttons :

```
<Button id="button1" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
<Button id="button2" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
<Button id="button3" onAction="#handleButtonAction"/>
```

Inside the controller :

```
@FXML
private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
    // Button was clicked, change color
    ((Button)event.getTarget).setStyle("-fx-background-color:PINK");
}
```